# Shrinking window with absolutely positioned element beyond its 'min-width' keeps 'left' value but destroys 'right' value

Tags: html, css, layout

I have [this html and css code](http://jsbin.com/bentley4/12/edit). When I shrink the window width to the minimum size of `div.element2` there is still a space of `20px` at the `left`. The space on the `right` however disappears when I shrink beyond the `min-width` value.

How can I keep the `20px` space at the right as well?

Answer (score 0):

The min-width is stopping it shrink below 340px. If you remove that then it will keep the 20px margin but will, obviously, not always be above 340px wide.

Comment: Off course, but I meant to imply keeping the `min-width` value. Why does the space disappear on the right side but not on the left side when shrinking? It must be possible to keep the space on the right side as well, no? If not that would be VERY strange and in that case I would like to know how to shrink while making both the left and right space disappear.

Comment: You're giving it 3 restrictions that can't all be followed and all stay correct so one has to go I suppose. You could probably do what you want with media queries though. - http://jsbin.com/bentley4/17/edit